# SequenceMatcher: Recording no match just once?

Tags: python, if-statement, sequencematcher

I am using `SequenceMatcher` to find a set of words within a group of texts. The problem I am having is that I need to **record when it does not find a match**, but **one time** per text. If I try an if statement, it gives me a result each time the comparison to another word fails.

```
names=[JOHN, LARRY, PETER, MARY]
files = [path or link]

  for file in files: 
     for name in names:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, name, file).ratio() > .9:
             do something
        else:
             print name + 'not found'
```

I have also tried `re.match` and `re.find` and I encounter the same problem. 
The code above is a simple version of what I am doing. I'm new to Python too.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? What should the output be if a word is found more than once? And if only once? And if it is not found at all?

Comment: Yes. The output if a name is found is some information regarding that person that comes right after the name. Every person is mentioned only one time in a text, but not every person is in every text. If a person is not in a given text, I want to keep a record of that. The reason it is so important is because I am creating  `csv ` file in which each column is a name. Does this help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret your comment to the question correctly (but I am not 100% sure!), this might illustrate the general mechanism you can follow:

```
>>> text = 'If JOHN would be married to PETER, then MARY would probably be unhappy'
>>> names = ['JOHN', 'LARRY', 'PETER', 'MARY']
>>> [text.find(name) for name in names]
[3, -1, 28, 40]  #This list will be always long as the names list
```

What I mean by "mechanism you can follow" is that `SequenceMatcher` (that I substituted with the builtin method `find`) should not only work as a test [True|False] but should already output the information you want to store.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to keep track of matched names and not print them if they've already been printed:

```
seen = {}
for file in files:
    for name in names:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, name, file).ratio() > .9:
            do something
        elif name not in seen:
            seen[name] = 0
            print name + 'not found'
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Though I placed `seen=[]` between the first `for` and the second `for` so that it resets for each file.